# Maximization of the sum of the norms of vectors in three dimensions.

Tags: optimization, vectors, vector-analysis

Suppose we have a collection of fixed vectors $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and we add another vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to each of the fixed vectors. How does one maximise the sum of their norms, as in the following expression: $|a + x| + |b + x| + |c + x|$?

My first instinct is this is a classic vector classic/optimization problem, but my heads not stuck on right and I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: This sum is not bounded. It tends to $\infty$ as $\|x\| \to \infty$.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Maybe I don't understand the question I'm trying to solve. I'll think on it for a minute.

Comment: @Daedalus: Perhaps you want to find $x$ which _minimizes_ that sum? If so, then if $a,b,c$ are not collinear, choose $x$ as the the negative (reflection through the origin) of the circumcenter of the triangle with vertices $a,b,c$.

Comment: @quasi It turns out there's extra information I wasn't given. I'll make the appropriate edits to the question soon.